# How do I format time in SSRS to HH:MM AM/PM format?

Tags: datetime, reporting-services

I was tasked with augmenting the following code to display the time without seconds, and with AM/PM:

```
=IIF(Fields!New_Date.Value <> "NO CHANGE", FormatDateTime(IIF(Fields!New_Date.Value = "NO CHANGE","1/1/12",Fields!New_Date.Value),DateFormat.ShortDate), "") &
IIF(Fields!New_Time.Value <> "NO CHANGE",FormatDateTime(IIF(Fields!New_Time.Value = "NO CHANGE","00:00",Fields!New_Time.Value),DateFormat.ShortTime), "")
```

In realizing that FormatDateTime was insufficient for what I was trying to do, I found the following did not work (just looking at the snippit that relates to the time fields), :

```
Format(IIF(Fields!New_Time.Value = "NO CHANGE","00:00",Fields!New_Time.Value),"HH:mm tt")
```

Or this

```
Format(IIF(Fields!New_Time.Value = "NO CHANGE","00:00",Fields!New_Time.Value),"HH:MM tt")
```

I'm getting the format codes from [here](http://thavash.wordpress.com/2007/10/02/date-formatting-in-reporting-services-list-of-format-codes/).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This question and answer are both of low quality; what exactly needs to be fixed in your question? What doesn't work?  How much searching was done, when [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-us/sqlreportingservices/thread/3042602f-1e44-43ae-8b5b-22da1a14c67c) is the first link I found, which says your solution doesn't work.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding something. I was told that the QA environment this site holds allows it to work a bit like a wiki, a sort of place to hold useful info. The reality is, I did do quite a bit of searching before finding the answer below (which is tested).

Comment: Think if someone else read your question, "could someone tell me how to fix this?"  You don't state what's wrong, what error you are getting, or what you're trying to fix, other than some sort of formatting issue.  If someone else sees this question, they won't know if your answer applies or not, because it's not even clear what problem you're having.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense - I was thinking more in terms of "something else to try" because it's rare that a problem case matches exactly (i.e. if I were to over specify). My takeaway here is "alright, so I didn't include enough info - I should at least provide enough so the reader has some idea what I'm trying to achieve". Is that correct?

Comment: Thank you LittleBobbyTables - I'll be sure to fix this. Kind Regards.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So I found that because I was essentially trying to format a textbox, SSRS never really 'knew' that it was a time field. While I'm not 100% sure my reasoning is correct, it does explain why the following works:

```
Format(CDate(IIF(Fields!New_Time.Value = "NO CHANGE","00:00",Fields!New_Time.Value)),"hh:mm tt")
```

Comment: Yeah, I found I had to cast the `time` field as `datetime` in order for it to format it using time formats.

Answer (score 10):

If your data is in simple textbox(or table cell) you have easer solution.

right click on the textbox > properties :

use the following:
[image]

Answer (score 7):

The other answers are correct, but the key difference to know with the format is:

```
 h:mm tt --> 12-hour clock (e.g. 5:30 PM)
hh:mm tt --> 12-hour clock with a leading zero, if necessary (e.g. 05:30 PM)
 H:mm    --> 24-hour clock (e.g. 1:30 for 1:30 AM)
HH:mm    --> 24-hour clock with a leading zero, if necessary (e.g. 01:30 for 1:30 AM)
```

Answer (score 5):

From Text Box Properties -> Number -> Custom Category:

Try to input this:

dd-MMM-yy hh:mm tt