# Format time in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have this code in SSRS Reporting:
`=": " + First(Fields!MY_TIME.Value, "MYDATASET")`
which prints the time in 02:31:15. But what I really want is to be able to change it to 12hour time style. E.g 2:31:15 PM.

Is there a way to do this?
I tried using `=format(Fields!MY_TIME.Value, "h:mm:ss tt")` but it kept complaining of the dataset.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you tried -> =format(First(Fields!MY_TIME.Value, "MYDATASET") , "h:mm:ss tt")

Comment: @RossBush I just tried your suggestion but it just prints h:mm:ss tt :-(

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14983362/how-do-i-format-time-in-ssrs-to-hhmm-am-pm-format

Comment: What is the column type in the table/view?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of formatting with an expression, you can directly change the format in the textbox Properties window. Select the textbox you want formatted, go to the Properties window (shortcut F4), and put in **h:mm:ss tt** in the Format box to get your desired 12 hr format.

[image]

[image]